# Flutter Firebase Login not returning the right screen, until reload, how to programatically reload?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

The following is the code for my main.dart, here I am trying to return the Login screen if the user is not currently logged in or the home screen if the user is logged in.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'SBR+',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
    print('here');

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      print('Logged In!');
      return HomeScreen();
    }
    return LoginScreen();
  }
}
```

But as the use logs in (and the 'Logged In!' does print), it does not change automatically to the home screen. Not until I do a hard reset... anyone knows how to fix this and make it go to the home screen automatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to check logged User:

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: StreamBuilder<User>(
  stream: _auth.userChanges(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData ? HomePage() : LoginPage(),
 ));
 }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue with this.